# Choose only year and month in Datepicker Material for Angular 5

Tags: datepicker, angular-material, angular5

I use material (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) for angular 5. Can we choose in the DatePicker only year and month (I do not want to choose day, day must be choose by default)?
For example:
- if the user selects july/2017, the component parse it to the first day of july. Something like new Date(2017,6,1);

Comment: According to docs https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api and to sources https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.ts, I'm afraid there is no such feature at this moment

Answer (score 0):

With Angular Material 5. It isnt possible, only with Material >= 6.